# Cursor jumping to the end of text if edit made to previous text

Tags: javascript, text, cursor, field

I have this some-what working JavaScript code. The thing that I can't figure out, is why the cursor jumps to the end of the text in my text field after I make an edit to something earlier in the text.

Is there some way I can keep the cursor in its current position if I make an edit to some previous text?

Here is the working page: http://rebol.vlexo.net/Programming/keys/esp/esp_keyboard.htm

...and the JS specific code...

```
// This code checks for a certain keypress combo. For example cx, Cx, gx, Gx, etc...
// The hard to type esperanto characters we aim to insert.

var esperanto = [
    ['cx','\u0109'],  ['gx','\u011D'],
    ['hx','\u0125'],  ['jx','\u0135'],
    ['sx','\u015D'],  ['ux','\u016D'],

    ['Cx','\u0108'],  ['Gx','\u011C'],
    ['Hx','\u0124'],  ['Jx','\u0134'],
    ['Sx','\u015C'],  ['Ux','\u016C']
];

document.onkeyup = changeChars;

function changeChars(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if(KeyID == 88)
    {
        var tmp = document.getElementById('TArea').value;
        for (var i=0; i<esperanto.length; i++) {
            re = new RegExp(esperanto[i][0],"g");
            tmp = tmp.replace(re,esperanto[i][1]);
        }
        document.getElementById('TArea').value = tmp;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is you are replacing the entire text value.  You will need to save the cursor position before performing the replace and re-set it afterward.  See this article for more information: http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just replacing characters, and not inserting or deleting 
more than a line's worth of characters before the cursor position,
you can read the tArea.scrollTop value before the switch, and reset it after.